# Server port busy issue with TCP Communication in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, server

i have used TCP communication in C# for client server communication.

Many of the clients are trying to connect to TCP server at a time.

i am facing server port busy issue. below is my server and client code.

is there any way, i can solve the server port busy issue.

```
Server Code
     /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void initializeListener(int iPortNumber,int iActivationPortNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                // BLTablePrototype.TablePrototypeDetails();
                System.Net.IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

                serverSocket = new TcpListener(ipaddress, iPortNumber);

                try
                {
                    serverSocket.Stop();

                }
                catch { }

                serverSocket.Start();

                Common.BLConstants.isListnerStarted = true;



                //StartAccept();
                //WaitForClients();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


        public void ReceiveTCP()
        {  
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (serverSocket.Pending())
                    {
                        TcpClient client = client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();                        
                        if (client.Connected)
                        {
                            Thread thread = new Thread(WorkThread);
                            thread.Start(client);
                        }                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }


client Code

  client = new TcpClient();
                var result = client.BeginConnect(Wipro.EUA.Library.Cryptography.Decrypt(Common.BLConstants.strServerIPAddress), iPortnumber, null, null);
                result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                if (client.Connected)
                {

                    byte[] SendingBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XElement.ToString());
                    netstream = client.GetStream();

                    int NoOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(SendingBuffer.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(BLConstants.iBufferSize)));
                    int TotalLength = (int)SendingBuffer.Length, CurrentPacketLength, FinalLength = 0, RemainingLength = TotalLength;
                    for (int k = 0; k < NoOfPackets; k++)
                    {
                        if (RemainingLength > BLConstants.iBufferSize)
                        {
                            if (k == 0)
                                CurrentPacketLength = k * BLConstants.iBufferSize;
                            else
                                CurrentPacketLength = k * BLConstants.iBufferSize;

                            FinalLength = CurrentPacketLength + BLConstants.iBufferSize;
                            RemainingLength = TotalLength - FinalLength;
                            netstream.Write(SendingBuffer, CurrentPacketLength, BLConstants.iBufferSize);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CurrentPacketLength = FinalLength;
                            netstream.Write(SendingBuffer, CurrentPacketLength, TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength);
                        }
                    }
                }

                client.EndConnect(result);
                isSuccess = true;
```

i have used TCP communication in C# for client server communication.

Many of the clients are trying to connect to TCP server at a time.

i am facing server port busy issue. below is my server and client code.

is there any way, i can solve the server port busy issue.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(30000)` that's a good way to contribute to clients timing out connecting

Comment: The TcpListener default to allowing 100 client to connect. You do not need to do "new" for each client.  You are getting an error because the listener is connecting to the virtual listening address in the computer with IPortNumber and only one connection can be made with that port number.  To handle multiple clients use the Asyn method.  Every time a new client connects the Accept method will give a new Client socket object.

Answer (score 1):

The issue as @MickyD commented, is the line:

```
Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

You accept only one connection and then sleeps for 30 seconds. Obviously, clients that will try to connect during those 30 seconds, will not get a reponse (timeout).

Actually, the solution is very simple.
You don't need all that login with the `Pending` and `Sleep`
It's enough to use only `AcceptTcpClient`.

`AcceptTcpClient` is a blocking method. It will block until a connection arrives.

The reason for using `Pending` is if you don't want to block, but you are blocking any way with the `Thread.Sleep(30000)`

All this is covered by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx):

> AcceptTcpClient is a blocking method that returns a TcpClient that you can use to send and receive data. Use the Pending method to determine if connection requests are available in the incoming connection queue if you want to avoid blocking.

Also, you don't need to check if the client is connected(You are getting a connected connection...)
So, your loop can become simpler:

```
while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = client = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();                        
    Thread thread = new Thread(WorkThread);
    thread.Start(client);
}
```